# Probability beta distribution problem

Tags: probability-distributions

A beam of length $1$ is rigidly supported at both ends. Experience shows that
whenever the beam is hit at a random point, it breaks at a position $X$ units from the right end,
where X is a beta random variable. If $E[X]=2/5$ and $\operatorname{var}(X)=1/25$,

Im trying to find P$(1/4 <X< 1/2)$

Comment: Excuse the error, I have made the correction.thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say, beta distribution are necessary parameters $\alpha, \beta$:

$\displaystyle E(X)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}=2/5, \quad D(X)=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1))}=1/25\quad \Rightarrow \alpha = 2, \beta = 3$

$\Rightarrow P(1/4 <X< 1/2)=beta(0.5)-beta(0.25)$, beta(x) is the distribution function B(x,2,3,0,1)

$\Rightarrow P = BETA(0.5)-BETA(0.25)=0.6875-0.2617 = 0.4258$